# Is there an efficient way to re-unwrap a specific part of a mesh only?

Tags: mesh, uv

During texturing I noticed some rather ugly stretching section and I'd like to adjust a couple of seams, but since I manually adited the UV islands after unwrapping I'd like to avoid having to unwrap the whole thing again. Is there a "best way" of doing this?

[image]
[image]